# Laravel distinct on join results not working in query builder

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.6

I have a posts table that has join query with 4 other tables. 3 of them are one to one relations but the 4th is one to many. I want the query to return only 1 row for each post. What i am trying so far is like this-

```
$query = DB::table('posts')
                ->select('posts.*',
                        'subcategories.subcategory_title_en',
                        'subcategories.subcategory_title_bn',
                        'categories.category_title_en',
                        'categories.category_title_bn',
                        'users.*',
                        'postimages.postimage_thumbnail'
                        )
                ->join('subcategories', 'subcategories.subcategory_id', '=', 'posts.subcategory_id')
                ->join('categories', 'categories.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.parent_category_id')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
                ->join('postimages', 'postimages.post_id', '=', 'posts.post_id');

        $query->groupBy('posts.post_id');

        echo $query->count();
        exit();
```

I have currently 50 posts in database, but the query returns all rows for each postimages, more than 1 row for each post that is. I thought distinct would only show each post_id once? What am i missing here?

I would prefer if someone tells me how to do this with query builder. As this will have a lot of searching on different columns and i want it to be as fast as possible.

This is a simpler version -

```
 $query = DB::table('posts')
                ->select('posts.*','postimages.postimage_thumbnail')
                ->join('postimages', 'postimages.post_id', '=', 'posts.post_id')
                ->groupBy('posts.post_id');


        echo $query->count();
        exit();
```

The strange thing is the SQL query that is shown by laravel " select `posts`.*, `postimages`.`postimage_thumbnail` from `posts` inner join `postimages` on `postimages`.`post_id` = `posts`.`post_id` group by `posts`.`post_id`" works fine in mysql

Comment: Which `postimages` row would you like to get? The one with the lowest `id`?

Comment: that would be best.

Comment: before someone posts eloquent way, i do have that running right now, bit it is important for this to be query builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use groupby

Try this code

```
 $query = DB::table('posts')
            ->select('posts.*',
                    'subcategories.subcategory_title_en',
                    'subcategories.subcategory_title_bn',
                    'categories.category_title_en',
                    'categories.category_title_bn',
                    'users.*',
                    'postimages.postimage_thumbnail'
                    )
            ->join('subcategories', 'subcategories.subcategory_id', '=', 'posts.subcategory_id')
            ->join('categories', 'categories.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.parent_category_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->join('postimages', 'postimages.post_id', '=', 'posts.post_id')->groupBy('posts.post_id');
```

In config/database.php at "mysql" change : 'strict' => true, to false

Comment: some strange error- it says SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db_ibikri.posts.user_id' isn't in GROUP BY (....

Comment: In config/database.php at "mysql" change :
'strict' => true,
to false.
Hope it helps!

Comment: ok now the error is gone but it selects all images of post_id = 1, how do i make it select 1st of all post_ids instead?

Comment: Wait i think that fixed it. I just had to use groupBy('postimages.post_id') thank you so much. I was stuck with it for so long

Comment: I edited the answer to include the part of changing mysql strict to false. Thank you again.